# Minimum euclidean distances and corresponding indices between array and array columns

Tags: python, performance, numpy, euclidean-distance

**UPDATE**

Just in case this is useful for anyone. As stated below, the Euclidean distance calculation and `np.argmin` accounted for almost all of the runtime. By rewriting the distance calculation with `numba` I was able to shave off at least 20% on most cases when compared to the already fast `np.einsum`.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def calculateDistances_numba(currentLocation, traces)

    deltaX = traces[:, 0, :] - currentLocation[0]
    deltaY = traces[:, 1, :] - currentLocation[1]
    deltaZ = traces[:, 2, :] - currentLocation[2]

    distances = (deltaX**2 + deltaY**2 + deltaZ**2)*0.5

    return distances
```

~~~~

**Problem**

I have a large array, `vertices.shape = (N, 3); N ~ 5e6`, describing the 3D vertices of an unstructured mesh. I have `n` smaller arrays of coordinates and data which I would like to linearly interpolate onto `vertices`. These are stored along the 3rd axis of another array, `traces.shape = (L, 3, n); L ~ 2e4; n ~ 2e3`. For each vertex (row in `vertices`), I want to *quickly* find the two closest points which are from different small arrays (pages in `traces`, i.e. their index along `axis=2` is different). By closest, I mean Euclidean distance `d = (deltaX**2 + deltaY**2 + deltaZ**2)`. The purpose of this function is to linearly interpolate between two known values to the points in vertices.

My current function works reasonably well but becomes prohibitively slow for the expected array sizes given above (8+ hours). I have gone through my entire code and can definitively say this calculation is the expensive one.

**Current Function**

```
import numpy as np

def interpolate(currentLocation, traces, nTraces):
    # Calculate the Euclidean distance between currentLocation and all points
    # in the search bracket. Einsum was found to be faster than np.linalg.norm as well as 
    # standard numpy operations.
    # Distances is a 2D array of shape (L, n) and corresponds to the Euclidean distance
    # between currentLocation and every point in traces.
    deltas = traces - currentLocation[None, :, None]
    distances = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', deltas, deltas)**0.5

    # Along axis = 1 is definitely a little bit faster 
    # but haven't implemented.
    # rowIndices is a 1D array whose elements are the indices of the 
    # smallest distance for each page (small array) of traces.
    rowIndices = np.argmin(distances, axis=0)

    # Get the actual distances
    min_distances = distances[rowIndices, np.arange(nTraces)]

    # Indices of two smallest traces (pages)
    columnIndices = np.argpartition(min_distances, 2)[:2]

    # Row indices of the two closest points
    rowIndices = rowIndices[columnIndices]

    # Distances to two closest points
    closePoints_distances = min_distances[columnIndices]

    # Calculate the interpolant weights based on the distances
    interpolantWeights = closePoints_distances/np.sum(closePoints_distances)

    # Return the indices because I need to retrieve the data for the close points
    # Return the interpolant weights to interpolate the data once retrieved
    return rowIndices, columnIndices, interpolantWeights

vertices = np.random.rand(200, 3)
traces = np.random.rand(100, 3, 10)
nTraces = traces.shape[-1]

# This is a simplified version of what actually happens.
for index, currentLocation in enumerate(np.arange(vertices.shape[0])):
    interpolate(currentLocation, traces, nTraces)
```

**%timeit Output**

```
%timeit interpolater(currentLocation, streamlineBlock, nStreamlines)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.8 ms per loop
```

Because of the structure of the data, I am able to choose just a chunk of `traces` to search (L~2e3) which markedly reduces runtime. The bracket to search is a function of currentLocation.

```
%timeit interpolaterNew(...)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.27 ms per loop
```

**cProfile Output**

cProfile tells me that np.einsum and np.argmin are the slowest - in fact they're the vast majority of the calculation. Note that this is for my code on a small subset of data and therefore may not reflect the above function exactly.

```
4251460 function calls (4151427 primitive calls) in 17.907 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
50012    7.236    0.000   17.063    0.000 vc3d_traces.py:554(interpolateToVertices)
50012    3.940    0.000    3.940    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.c_einsum}
50012    3.505    0.000    3.505    0.000 {method 'argmin' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
100025    0.291    0.000    0.291    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
50012    0.289    0.000   17.352    0.000 frame.py:4238(f)
50012    0.223    0.000    0.223    0.000 {method 'searchsorted' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
100024    0.191    0.000    0.346    0.000 indexing.py:1815(_convert_key)
1    0.190    0.190   17.905   17.905 {pandas._libs.lib.reduce}
100024    0.159    0.000    0.504    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1730(sum)
100024    0.155    0.000    0.155    0.000 {method 'get_value' of 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine' objects}
```

**Question(s)**

I am now at a bit of a loss as to how to improve performance. Given that the distance calculation and argmin sort is the most expensive, is it possible to 'vectorise' these steps, applying the calculation to the entire 'vertices' array? I did try this by broadcasting into axis=4 without success - the computer froze. Does the cProfile report point towards anything else or is there anything glaringly bad in my code? Can anyone point me towards a better method? Finally, using tqdm, there is a large, quick decrease in the iterations per second (250 down to <175 within the first few minutes) - is this to be expected?

Comment: Have u looked into using a kdtree https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

Comment: @BiRico I haven't applied a kdtree to this problem for two reasons 1) I think i would need a tree for each small array (`n` trees) in order to return two points from seperate arrays. 2) I don't think I take advantage of cutting out chunks of traces without retraining trees. But I'll check it and `sklearn.neighbours.KDtree` out, thanks.

Comment: Update: kdtrees don't seem to be a good option for this specific problem for the reasons specified above. UNLESS only one tree can be trained and queried which will return two points from separate small arrays.